# HTML/CSS Making a Link a Background Image

Tags: html

I have tried looking up several ways to make my specific image the background of a webpage, but it hasn't worked.
I tried

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("ice_dna.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

to no avail. I even tried

```
<body background="File:Ice-Binding-DNA--.jpeg">
<p><a href="http://*LINK*"</a></p>
</body>
```

But this just made the background into a link to the image... I tried making the background just the link, but that didn't work either. The only way I can display the image is as img src="...". Is there a way to make that image source into the background?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here?

Comment: Most likely, the problem is that the image URL isn't pointing to where the image actually is. Relative URLs can be tricky like that; you might want to try using the full URL of the image and see if that helps. But without a [testable example](/help/mcve), we can really only guess.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't give you guys the link to this :/ I can't use images stored on my computer for this project, they are all on a type of registry. When you're saying use the full URL, are you saying to use to webpage URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make the page itself "full height". By default, it has no height. And then you should be able to apply your background:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body { 
    background-image: url("img_girl.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to use the URL of the webpage that stores the image? If not, is there a way that I can do that?

Comment: Yes, lets say you have an image like `http://i.imgur.com/HlmWDMU.jpg`, you can link to it like so: 
`background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/HlmWDMU.jpg");`

Comment: That's weird then... instead of making a background image, all of this just showed up as text on the screen... I don't know HTML nor CSS at all, so would I have to declare that I am changing my code to CSS before I do this?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code i listed here should go in your `<style>` tags. Sorry! I assumed that was obvious. :P

Comment: Okay, I just did the style thing and the text went away, but the image is still not on the screen

Comment: Do you have a testable example so I can see what's happening? Maybe put your code on https://codepen.io/pen/ so I can see whats up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152781/discussion-between-drjessop-and-bitz).

Answer (score 1):

If you can display the image using `<img src="...">`, then there shouldn't be anything wrong with the image itself.  Your CSS also looks good to me.  Indeed, it works just fine in a snippet like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Since you say that you're using an inline `<style>` element for your CSS, the problem can't even be caused by relative URLs (which, in an external style sheet, would get resolved relative to the location of the style sheet rather than the location of the HTML page).

Thus, I'm forced to conclude that your problem cannot be reproduced as described, and must be caused by something that you have not described in your question.  I have therefore voted to [close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) your question, as any answers to it at this point would have to be pure guesswork.

<sup>Ps. This really should have been a comment, but one can't include snippets in a comment.  I've instead marked this answer as Community Wiki, so that I won't get any rep from up/down votes to it.</sup>